# GridView PAGING inside UpdatePanel does not work for second page change, why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, updatepanel, paging

I got two updatepanels which one of them contains a gridview. The problem is the Pagination works properly only for the first time.

Here is the markup:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upAnswers" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvAnswers" runat="server" CssClass="gv" Width="100%" ShowHeader="false" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="2" EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="true" OnPageIndexChanging="gvAnswers_PageIndexChanging" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#eee">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Questions" ShowHeader="False">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblQuestions" onclick=<%# Eval("FaqID", "$('.lblAnswers_{0}').toggle('fast')") %> CssClass="block" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>'></asp:Label>
                        <asp:Panel ID="pnlS1" runat="server" CssClass='<%# Eval("FaqID", "lblAnswers_{0}") %>' style="display: none;">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Question") %>' CssClass="block bold"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblAnswers" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Answer") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="upgAnswers" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="upAnswers" DisplayAfter="300">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <div id="uiBlock" class="uiBlock">
        </div>
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

and the code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        GetAnsweredPublicFAQs();
    }
}

protected void GetAnsweredPublicFAQs()
{
    DataSet ds = cFAQs.getAnsweredPublicFAQs();

    gvAnswers.DataSource = ds;
    gvAnswers.DataBind();
}

protected void gvAnswers_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    gvAnswers.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GetAnsweredPublicFAQs();
    gvAnswers.DataBind();
    upAnswers.Update();
}
```

As ref, I use ASP.NET 4.0 C#.

Any kind help would be highly appreciated.

Regards,
Kardo

Comment: have you tried to use UpdateMode="Always"? moreover, put ChildrenAsTriggers without putting any Trigges is useless, because the UpdatePanel with UpdateMode="Conditional" will be updated whenever a children control makes postback.

Comment: What does happen the second time?  All you've said is that pagination only works properly of the first time.

Comment: @jadarnel27 the second time nothing happens.

Comment: @AlessioCavaleri: when I try UpdateMode="Always", it's not working even for the first time, without any error.

Comment: On the second time, do you hit the PageIndexChanging event?  What is the value of e.NewPageIndex at that point?

Comment: @jadarnel27: it always hits the PageIndexChanging event and the value of e.NewPageIndex is as expected (regarding the page no I hid, the value is correct). And the most important every thing works fine without UpdatePanel.

Answer (score 3):

Change your UpdatePanel declaration to start like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upAnswers" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="gvAnswers" EventName="PageIndexChanging" />
```

Whenever I've had trouble with these `UpdatePanel`s, I find explicitly declaring the Triggers to be helpful.  Especially when you're using a "non-default" event to trigger an AsyncPostBack (SelectedIndexChanged is the "default" event for the GridView).

Also, ChildrenAsTriggers defaults to true, so I removed that from the markup.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work. As before, when I go to page 2, hitting the other page numbers do nothing.

Comment: @rick_schott hi, do you  have any idea on my issue?

Comment: @Kardo What's the general structure of the rest of your page? Is this UpdatePanel nested inside another UpdatePanel or something?

Comment: the rest of page is pretty normal, a page with master. nothing especial. I've tried many different solution, such enabling or disabling viewstate of page or item, adding ScriptManager sp = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this);sp.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(gvAnswers); to page, etc...

Comment: I tried the updatepanel and gridview in a new blank webform without master and amazingly it worked perfect. now I should find out what affects the code.

Comment: @Kardo Oh that's interesting.  So something in your MasterPage code-behind is interrupting the paging or some nonsense like that?

Comment: @jadranel27 : it seems this script caused the problem:         function pageLoad() {
            $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
                show_title: false,
                allow_resize: true,
                theme: 'facebook',
                deeplinking: false,
                ie6_fallback: true,
                social_tools: false
            });
        }

Comment: at the other hand, the above script is necessary for "pretty photo" to work fine :( do you have any idea how to fix the script to not affect the Paging?

Comment: @Kardo I haven't used "pretty photo" before, but it looks like you're using jQuery. Where is that "pageLoad()" function called from?

Comment: @jadranel27  Yes, that's JQuery and it's at the bottom of the page, just before closing tag of FORM.

Comment: @Kardo Try waiting til the DOM is ready, perhaps: `$(pageLoad() { $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({ show_title: false, allow_resize: true, theme: 'facebook', deeplinking: false, ie6_fallback: true, social_tools: false }); });`  The other thing, if this is affecting items inside your UpdatePanel, you're going to need to call it after our async postbacks somehow.